# How to split the bill in a formal way?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, american-english

What is the polite and formal way to say if I would like to split the bill?

That was a time I went to a casual business meeting and the person was kind enough to pay for my bill. And all I said is thank you but the person doesn't have to do so and I was wondering what is the polite way to say split the bill and in fact, **I would like to pay on my own**. But I don't think "Let's go Dutch" or "Let's split the bill" will be the formal way in this situation. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the English part of the question is that “Let’s split the check” is acceptable. We might also say “I would prefer to pay my share of the bill.”

For more specific advice about how to handle the situation without seeming ungrateful, you may want to look at the [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange site. Etiquette in specific situations is on-topic there, and I think they might welcome your question if you are looking for more than simple advice on phrasing.